# How do you make a systemd service as the last service on boot?

Tags: systemd

Many years ago, we can write our startup-script into `/etc/rc.local`. After all system services loaded, your script will run.

Now, we use systemd, we don't have `rc.local` anymore. Systemd starts the service parallel. You can write your own service to act a rc.local` but you can't ensure it will run after all system services loaded.

Is there a way to do it? Or we have to use `Before` and `After` in the systemd service file?

Comment: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Comment: Systemd, not Upstart!!

Comment: Specify name and version OS?

Comment: OS: Arch Linux, Version: N/A

Comment: http://rus-linux.net/kos.php?name=/papers/boot/boot-05.html

Comment: /etc/rc.conf edit

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Writing_rc.d_scripts

Comment: rc.conf is deprecated and removed.

Comment: grep initdefault /etc/inittab

Comment: @比尔盖子 Why "last", do you not know the dependencies of the script, or do you want it last just to be safe?

Comment: Just be safe...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In systemd it is advised to use `Before=` and `After=` to order your services nicely around the other ones.

But since you asked for a way without using `Before` and `After`, you can use:

```
Type=idle
```

which as [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) explains:

> Behavior of `idle` is very similar to `simple`; however, actual execution of the service program is delayed until all active jobs are dispatched. This may be used to avoid interleaving of output of shell services with the status output on the console. Note that this type is useful only to improve console output, it is not useful as a general unit ordering tool, and the effect of this service type is subject to a 5s timeout, after which the service program is invoked anyway.

Comment: Hi, would you care to elaborate the syntax if I was gonna use before or after?

Comment: Somewhat different topic, but if someone wants to run user processes separate from system processes, there's https://askubuntu.com/a/859583/457417

Comment: worked perfectly to set `/proc/sys/kernel/modules_disabled` to `1` at the end of the boot process

Comment: The quoted excerpt for the `idle` Type includes this: `Note that this type is useful only to improve console output, it is not useful as a general unit ordering tool, and the effect of this service type is subject to a 5s timeout, after which the service program is invoked anyway.` Doesn't that mean, effectively, that processes set as `idle` will only be delayed by 5 secs, and further that `idle` will not *necessarily* accomplish the OP's stated objective: `... run after all system services loaded.`??

Answer (score 10):

The best way to make sure our service will execute after all other enabled services is to create your own target and make it run after `multi-user.target`.

Typically:

1. Create a target unit `/etc/systemd/system/custom.target` file with `AllowIsolate=yes`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Custom Target
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

2. Create you service unit file `/etc/systemd/system/last_command.service` with `After=multi-user.target` and `WantedBy=custom.target`

```
[Unit]
Description=My custom command
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my_last_command.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=custom.target
```

3. Create the `/etc/systemd/system/custom.target.wants` directory
4. Link your `last_command.service` into `/etc/systemd/system/custom.target.wants`

```
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/last_command.service \
  /etc/systemd/system/custom.target.wants/last_command.service
```

5. Reload systemd with `systemctl daemon-reload`
6. Set the system default target as `custom.target`

```
systemctl set-default custom.target
```

7. Optionally, you may want apply immediately the `custom.target`

```
systemctl isolate custom.target
```

This way, for each reboot, your last_command service will be executed after the `multi-user.target` is reached.

Comment: Does this mean that specifying `After=multi-user.target` in a unit will have the same effect?

Comment: @HoshSadiq Not necessarily, After= tells "this service should start after all services wanted and required by Multi-user target" but it tells nothing about a situation where Multi-user.target is not started for any reason. That is why `custom.target` also has the `Requires=multi-user.target` directive and why `custom.target` is set to the default target. This way by calling `custom.target` the system calls `multi-user.target`.
More [in the doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#After=)

Comment: You can also just create this target under `multi-user.target` directory and control the `Before=` and `After=` in there. If messing with mount points often you need `nofail` to avoid other services preventing your ordering.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on your definition of "booted". I assume you want it to run immediately after the getty starts. To do this, you need to add your service to `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/` directory. You should also ensure your file is using similar code to the other services in this directory. To run a custom service on bootup and shutdown (just beeps my motherboard buzzer) I use the following script in `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/service_name.service`

```
[Unit]
After=systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service
After=rc-local.service
Before=getty.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myinitscript.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/myinitscript.sh stop
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

`/usr/bin/myinitscript.sh` is executable and has a shebang at the start.

Note that not everything will be started at this point in the boot, but this is the point at which the logon prompt appears to the user

Although this does use `Before=` and `After=`, it was for me much more understandable and actually works; I didn't find the above answer informative enough. This is also allows you to use both `ExecStart=` and `ExecStop=`, rather than being limited to a `Type=simple`-like service.